# Extract Foreign Key Constraint and Reference Column from SQL Server table's query

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I use the following query to list all table constraints, which works well in extracting constraint needed to alter the output table (adding primary key, unique constraint).

```
select table_view,
    object_type, 
    constraint_type,
    constraint_name,
    details
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details]
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    select schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name
    from sys.foreign_keys fk
        inner join sys.tables fk_tab
            on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        inner join sys.tables pk_tab
            on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        inner join sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols
            on fk_cols.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        con.[definition]
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition]
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) a
order by table_view, constraint_type, constraint_name
```

https://dataedo.com/kb/query/sql-server/list-all-table-constraints

However, it does not work in case of foreign key as a foreign key constraint (column) and its reference column is needed.

```
ALTER TABLE row16.table_view
ADD CONSTRAINT row16.contraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (**row16....**) REFERENCES row16.details(**row16....**);

 || actual value

ALTER TABLE DBO.AREA
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_AREA_DOM_AIRLINE
FOREIGN KEY (**should be 'airline_cd'**) REFERENCES DBO.DOM_AIRLINE(**should be 'cd'**);
```

[image]

I wanted to add foreign constraint using the following statement, but I don't know how I could define foreign key constraint and its reference column here..

I feel like there might be a need to make some changes to the table constraints query, but I just start learning SQL recently so I'm not familiar with the whole concept yet...

Here's table relation for reference
[image]

Please let me know if you need any more infos. Appreciated all your helps!